# custom tab to configurable products only

Tags: product, configurable-product

i added below code for custom tab

My New Custom Tab>My New Custom Tabcore/templatecatalog/product/mynewcustomtab.phtml

but it show for all products now if i want to enable it only for configurable product what should i do for it

Answer (score 1):

Magento have call new layout handler(`PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable`)  for configurable product.

In `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View` class at function `initProductLayout` magento is add ed new layout  `PRODUCT_TYPE_producttypeid"` 
see at

```
$update->addHandle('PRODUCT_TYPE_' . $product->getTypeId());
$update->addHandle('PRODUCT_' . $product->getId());
```

Depends on this,magento is calling different block on each type

In `catalog.xml` file you have seen magento is  `add Additional block dependant` on product type

```
  <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.configurable.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                    <label>Product Extra Info</label>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

You have seen that above code there magento is add some block depends on product type
just configgurable product dropdown.

So you  can do the same ways

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="yourBlockReferencName">
        <block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/mynewcustomtab.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```

You need `added` this code on `layout` file or `catalog.xml`

Comment: can u guide hwo to add in Magento2? for the configurable product in the frontend

Answer (score 0):

Check the below condition of before your tabs if product type is configurable then inside of for loop

if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):

or

$product->isConfigurable();

Hope this helps

Thanks